# Idiomatic translation of la justice à la peine

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I'm looking for an idiomatic English translation of the cover of today's  l'Humanité -- "la justice à la peine"

https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/feb/04/lhumanite-france-socialist-communist-newspaper

Google Translate's 'justice to the trouble' really doesn't seem to cut it... it feels more like 'justice has a price'.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably relevant: [être à la peine](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/être%20à%20la%20peine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to understand the following French expression:

> Être à la peine

Here is the definition:

> Être en difficulté.
>
> Cette expression tire sa signification du mot "peine" venant du latin *poena* qui veut dire "la punition", mais aussi "la souffrance". Ainsi, "être à la peine" signifie "être en souffrance morale ou physique".

So *la justice à la peine* means *la justice en difficulté*.

*[Source](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/18165/etre-a-la-peine/)*

There is also an intended pun, as often in newspapers titles. A *peine* is usually what the justice is deciding (i.e. a penalty, a sentence), not what it is suffering.

Comment: You should tell there is also a pun in the title.

Comment: Yep, I didn't feel super confortable about explaining it so I prefer to do not say something wrong, but please feel free to modify/add it to the answer if you want to :)

Answer (score -1):

**A** The use now considered of "à la peine" according to standard French is to be taken as meaning "**under a  burden**", "**in work (on something)**"; this is the traditionnal meaning and it is explained in the TLFi;

> 1 Travail physique très pénible.
>  
>     - Nous qui suons le jour et couchons sur la dure, Qui n'avons ici-bas que la peine et le mal.
>   - Ce sera toujours le mineur qui aura la peine, sans l'espoir d'un gigot de temps à autre, en récompense.
>
> **Dur (ou un adj. équivalent) à la peine**.
>   -  Ils sont *avares et durs* à la peine comme les Auvergnats.
>   - *Résistants* à la peine, capables de souffrir longtemps. Ce sont de simples hommes.
>   **Mourir, tuer qqn à la peine** Synon. mourir, tuer à la tâche. (Faire) travailler durement et sans relâche jusqu'à la mort.
>   - Ce gredin de gouvernement qui tuait ses employés à la peine, sans leur assurer seulement de quoi mourir.

- On pouvait les voir toute la journée (à la peine/à la tâche) dans des champs arides. (example of mine)
- C'est à la peine que l'on reconnait l'ouvrier. (example of mine)

If it is conceivable to use the expression in a zero adjective option, and I think it is, we do have a meaning for this sentence; "La justice est au travail" there being an ellipse of the verb "être".

In the TLFi you do find "à la peine" where "peine" is used in the sense of "effort or inconvenient"; however it must be followed by a complement (introduced by the preposition "**de**"). Therefore this cannot be the meaning in the title.

> 2. **La peine de** [suivi d'un verbe à l'inf., d'une prop. au subj., d'un subst. exprimant une idée verbale (rare)]. Ce que représente en fait de fatigue, d'effort, d'attention l'accomplissement d'un travail, d'une activité (désigné par le compl. prép. de ou par la prop. complét. ou par l'inf. dans la combinaison avec valoir ou être).
>      -Vous allez aux Tuileries? Faites-moi le plaisir de donner cette dépêche à Sa Majesté; vous m'éviterez **la peine du** voyage.
>
>    - Des milliers de malheureux qui sont au désespoir de ce petit froid, qui ne vous coûte tout au plus que **la peine de** souffler votre feu.
>    - Je ne me crus plus astreint **à la peine de** le comprendre.

To use it to mean "être en difficulté" as we have it in the [internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/18165/etre-a-la-peine/) implies a shift, an addition (recent) on the meaning of this expression, in a family of expression with the word peine" which is already intricate enough; if the matter is a question of difficulty, then let it be said as it is, "La justice en difficulté", and let's not distort language ill assimilated to divert it from its initial purpose and make it thus harder than necessary to learn and use.

> Cette expression tire sa signification du mot "peine" venant du latin "poena" qui veut dire "la punition", mais aussi "la souffrance". Ainsi, "être à la peine" <s>signifie "être en souffrance morale ou physique".</s>

Ther is no trace od this fixed phrase either in the TLFi or the "Académie"'s dittionary. 
The phrases in which "souffrance morale ou physique" is the meaning are of the sort found in the dictionary of the "Académie Française", shown below ;

> II. Souffrance du corps ou de l'esprit. 1. Effort qui coûte ; travail, fatigue que l'on s'impose pour accomplir quelque action ***en dépit de difficultés, d'obstacles***. Il n'a accompli cette tâche qu'avec peine. Je voudrais lui épargner cette peine. J'en suis venu à bout, mais non sans peine, au prix de grandes peines, de mille peines. Se donner de la peine. Travaillez, prenez de la peine, se dit par allusion à la fable de La Fontaine « Le Laboureur et ses enfants ». Être récompensé de sa peine, de ses peines.

There exists already a well established term to express "être dans la souffrance morale" ; it's "**être en peine**"; there is nothing wrong with it and the preposition reflects a much better logic than "**à**" ; there is no need for this awkward, anarchistic neologism. It is the result of a poor knowledge of the language; it is not found in the TLFi, which shows it's a half-baked neologism.

CONCLUSION

There is no other alternative than either to consider that the title means "La justice en difficulté" and consider as well that this is very bad French or either that the meaning is "La justice au travail" or "something as "La justice forcée au travail".

As can be read [here](http://www.lavoixdunord.fr/526602/article/2019-01-24/la-justice-la-peine-pour-la-rentree-du-tribunal-de-grande-instance) the most likely interpretation is that of the "bad French".